# Scraping Data from Google Spectrum Database

Tags: python, r, excel, web-scraping

I am working on Traffic prediction for which I am using [Google Spectrum Database](https://www.google.com/get/spectrumdatabase/). I need to scrap the output table which comes when address is given as Input (name of any city in the United States).

1. However, the URL remains the same even after giving Input and getting the table.
2. Also, the page does not get updated for a particular address on its own.
3. If I am saving the page as HTML, then I am able to extract the table using MS Excel.

I want to extract the table directly from website and after every one hour.Should I scrap data using Python, R or MS Excel ?

Comment: Are you using the [API](https://www.google.com/get/spectrumdatabase/business/)?

Comment: @msvalkon - No, I am not able to use the API as it needs FCC ID (which is there only for US devices) and the testing FCC ID provided by Google is not working.